# Get "last" row of the initial sequence

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a table as below

Example 1:

```
ID      Code
1       A002
2       A001
3       A001
4       A002
5       A001
6       A002
```

I want to get last row (initial sequence) of A001. Result should be ID = 3

Example 2:

```
ID      Code
1       A001
2       A001
3       A001
4       A002
5       A001
6       A002
```

I want to get last row (initial sequence) of A001. Result should be ID = 3

Example 3

```
ID      Code
1       A001
2       A002
3       A001
4       A002
5       A001
6       A002
```

I want to get last row (initial sequence) of A001. Result should be ID = 1

How do I do?

I tried to run below code

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id < (select min(t2.id)
              from t t2
              where t2.code <> 'A001'  -- not NOT EQUALS
             ) 
order by t1.id desc;
```

but in Example 1, it runs incorrect.

Comment: how about using min() and max()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative method using window functions:

```
select max(id)
from (select min(case when code <> 'A001' and id < min_a001_id
                      then id end
                 end) as min_next_id
      from (select t.*
                   min(case when code = 'A001' then id end) over () as min_a001_id
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where code = 'A001' and
      (min_next_id is null or id < min_next_id);
```

An alternative method uses `lead()` -- the first time the next id is not `A001`:

```
select min(id)
from (select t.*,
             lead(code) over (order by id) as next_code
      from t
     ) t
where code = 'A001' and
      (next_code is null or next_code <> 'A001')
```

Answer (score 0):

we can achieve this using simple `left join` plus `min()` and `max()` functions

```
select coalesce(max(t2.id), min(t1.id)) from t as t1
left join t t2 on t2.id = t1.id + 1 and t2.code = t1.code
where t1.code = 'A001';
```